# Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found and 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Error]

How to solve this problem. It's happen when I tried to run this error code? It involves package printing. I have tried to fix it but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

My flutter doctor

[image: flutter doctor results]

Answer (score 1):

`DecoderCallback` has been removed in Flutter 3.16, see the [release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.16.0#framework).

The package author has updated the usage of `DecoderCallback` to `ImageDecoderCallback`, so you can try using the latest version:

```yaml
dependencies:
  printing: ^5.11.1
```

Or if anything breaks, you can always check the [package changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/printing/changelog) and find a version that suits for your need.